# i am not able to get my required columns using $project.Following is my query

Tags: mongodb

i am not able to get my required columns using $project. My query is

```
db.RecordLogs.aggregate([
{$match: {
    $and: [
    {EmployeeId :  102365},{LoggingDate : {
    '$gte': ISODate("2019-06-15T04:00:00.000Z"),
    '$lte': ISODate("2019-06-16T03:59:59.999Z")
    }}]
}},
{$group: {_id : {Appname :"$AppName"},count : {"$sum":1}}},
{$project: {EmployeeName : 1, AgentId : 1}},
{$limit: 10}
])
```

Only grouped column is displayed.

Comment: your grouping appname and count.after pipeline project only thes two fields only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$push` for getting grouped items

```
db.RecordLogs.aggregate([
{$match: {
    $and: [
    {EmployeeId :  102365},{LoggingDate : {
    '$gte': ISODate("2019-06-15T04:00:00.000Z"),
    '$lte': ISODate("2019-06-16T03:59:59.999Z")
    }}]
}},
{$group: {_id : {Appname :"$AppName"},
    count : {"$sum":1},
    items : { $push: { "AgentId": "$AgentId", "EmployeeName": "$EmployeeName" } }
}},
{$limit: 10}
])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.RecordLogs.aggregate([
{$match: {
    $and: [
    {EmployeeId :  190192},{LoggingDate : {
    '$gte': ISODate("2019-06-15T04:00:00.000Z"),
    '$lte': ISODate("2019-06-16T03:59:59.999Z")
    }}]
}},
{$group: {
    _id : {
      Appname :"$AppName"
    },

      "EmployeeName": { "$first": "$EmployeeName"},


      "AgentId": { "$first": "$AgentId"},

   count : {"$sum":1}}},
{$limit: 10}
])
```

try thisss...